# How to install openEdx platform on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, openedx

1.I should choose which version is better?
2.the third step , Bootstrap the Ansible installation:

`$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/$OPENEDX_RELEASE/util/install/ansible-bootstrap.sh -O - | sudo -E bash`

The SSL connection fails to be established when the command is executed and the URL access in the command is 404

So how do I deploy openEdx platform on Ubuntu?Can someone help me? thank you

Comment: It seems your DNS is not configured properly, Please check with the domain register. Or if you are handling DNS then check the DNS records for your Open edX hosted IP in the DNS.